# How to use external dependencies in sbt's .scala files?

Tags: scala, sbt

This is for Scala 2.11.1 and sbt 0.13.5.

Say I have a Scala/sbt project with the following directory structure:

```
root/
  build.sbt
  src/ ..
  project/
    plugins.sbt
    build.properties
    LolUtils.scala
```

and I want to use some external library in `LolUtils.scala`. How is this generally accomplished in sbt?

If I simply add the libs I need into `build.sbt` via `libraryDependencies += ..` then it doesn't find them and fails on the import line with `not found: object ..`.

If I add a separate `project/build.sbt`, for some reason it starts failing to resolve my plugins, plus I need to manually specify the Scala version in the nested `project/build.sbt`, which is unnecessary duplication.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is your library using Scala 2.10? If you want to use your library in the build definition it should be compatible with the Scala version, that sbt is using. You should not override Scala version for build definition, I think.

Comment: @lpiepiora The versions are all fine, the lib is built against 2.11.

Comment: that's what I mean, sbt build definition is compiled using Scala 2.10.x. You've stated you're using Scala 2.11.1, which is fine for your project sources, but the sources in `project/` should be compiled using Scala 2.10.x

Comment: @lpiepiora Right, didn't cross my mind. The libs are available for 2.10 as well, is the main idea then putting those into `project/build.sbt` and building with 2.10 and keeping `root/build.sbt` on 2.11?

Comment: exactly, do not mess with `scalaVersion` in `project/build.sbt`, and it should work

Comment: @lpiepiora Tried it, works just fine if I don't mess with `scalaVersion` in the build's `build.sbt`. If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Full-Def.html) which means that it uses itself to compile a build definition, i.e. `*.sbt` files and `*.scala` files under `project` directory. To add extra dependencies to use them in the build definition you have to declare them in a `project/build.sbt`.

There is one caveat to that. You can set any `scalaVersion` to your project, that is in `build.sbt`, but you should not modify `scalaVersion` in the `project/build.sbt` as it might conflict with the version `sbt` itself uses (that may or may not lead to binary incompatibility for plugins).

Sbt 0.13.5 is using Scala 2.10.4, and the library you're going to use must be compatible with that particular version of Scala.

```
> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.5
...
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```